# Openpyxl worksheet object has no attribute move_range

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have the below code and it errors out on move_range for some reason. I am using openpyxl version 2.5.12. I tried updating to 2.6, but then it introduced some error related to Pandas deprecated NaT feature so I'd like to stay on 2.5.12 if possible. I have included the below modules imported from openpyxl as well.

```
import openpyxl

from openpyxl import load_workbook

from openpyxl import Workbook

from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo

from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet

from openpyxl.worksheet import worksheet

from openpyxl import worksheet


book = load_workbook(extract_file_loc)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
book.active = 4
ws = book.active
data = gpatuple

ws.append(gp_headers_tp)
  for row in data:
     ws.append(row)

tab = Table(displayName="PATH_FILE", ref=final_cord)

# Add a default style with striped rows and banded columns
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium2", showRowStripes=True)
tab.tableStyleInfo = style
ws.add_table(tab)
ws.move_range("G4:H10", rows=-1, cols=2)
ws.move_range(final_cord, rows=-1,cols=0)
book.save("extract.xlsx")
print "complete!"
```

Comment: if you do `dir(ws)` is `move_range` one of the available methods?

Comment: Hi David, here is some documentation that highlights move_range should be a feature. [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html) it doesn't seem to be one of the available methods when I printed dir(ws). My guess is move_range isn't in openpyxl 2.5.12? Are you familiar of where to go to verify this? I looked at the below changes and didn't see move_range listed as a change. [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html)

Comment: The dox is for the latest/stable version 2.6 I think. I'm not sure how to verify it in a previous version of the docs other than checking whether `'move_range' in dir(ws)`. If it's a new feature, you won't be able to use it in the older version.

Comment: you *may* want to look into/ ask a separate question about that pandas error. Seems like that would be an easy fix.

Comment: You need 2.6 for the feature: it's not covered in the 2.5.x docs